# Can't paint webview on Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, webview

I'm trying to track the events of a webview in my android kotlin application as indicated in this Medium article: https://medium.com/airasia-com-tech-blog/android-network-traffic-tracking-79d2bb957bc2
The problem I'm having is that I can't reach the onViewCreated (it doesn't print the Log in the console) and I don't know what I'm missing

**MyWebViewFragment**

```
class MyWebViewFragment : Fragment() {

   var isChuckerWebViewEnalbed = BuildConfig.DEBUG

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
      Log.d("MyWebViewFragment", "onViewCreated")
      val webView = view.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview_container)

      webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

      Log.d("MyWebViewFragment", "Loading URL: https://jmrtno.github.io/Blog_fotografia/")

      webView.loadUrl("https://jmrtno.github.io/Blog_fotografia/")

      // Configuración del WebViewClient para manejar errores
      webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
         override fun onReceivedError(
            view: WebView?,
            request: WebResourceRequest?,
            error: WebResourceError?
         ) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
            Log.e("MyWebViewFragment", "Error loading URL: ${error?.description}")
         }
      }

      webView?.let {
         webView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
         )

         webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
         webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
         webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
         webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)


      }

      if (isChuckerWebViewEnalbed) {

         ChuckerWebViewHelper.addJavascriptInterface(webView)

         val builder: OkHttpClient.Builder =
            OkHttpClient.Builder().cookieJar(JavaNetCookieJar(SyncCookieHandler(context)))
         builder.addInterceptor(ChuckerInterceptor(requireContext()))

         ChuckerWebViewHelper
            .enable(true)
            .addWebViewClient(webView)
            .setOkHttpClient(builder.build())
            .addInterceptHost("https://jmrtno.github.io/Blog_fotografia/")
            .interceptAllHosts(false)
            .interceptAllFileExtension(false)
            .handleRequestsWithPayload(true)
            .interceptPreflight(false)
            .setListener(object : ChuckerWebViewHelper.Listener() {
               override fun onHandleRequestViaOkHttp(request: WebResourceRequest) {
                  Log.d(
                     "onHandleRequestViaOkHttp",
                     "ChuckerWebViewHelper: okHttp handling  ${request.method} ${request.url}"
                  )
               }

               override fun onInvalidHostRegex(e: Exception) {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "response KO $e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                  Log.d("onInvalidHostRegex", "ChuckerWebViewHelper: $e")
               }

               override fun onFailedOKHttpRequest(request: WebResourceRequest, e: Exception) {
                  Log.d(
                     "onFailedOKHttpRequest",
                     "ChuckerWebViewHelper: okHttp handling failed  ${request.method} ${request.url}"
                  )

               }
            })

      }
   }

   override fun onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView()
      if (isChuckerWebViewEnalbed)
         ChuckerWebViewHelper.destroy()
   }

}
```

I also add the XML of the fragment and the MainActivity in case I'm missing something there:

**Fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/webview_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyWebViewFragment">
</WebView>
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         Log.d("MainActivity", "Fragment transaction")
         supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, MyWebViewFragment())
            .commit()
      }
   }
}
```

**MainActivity XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to override `onCreateView` first in your `MyWebViewFragment`, this is where view of the fragment is created. And then `onViewCreated` is called.

```
class MyWebViewFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    //Inflate your fragment layout here
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview, container, false)
}
...
}
```

Also consider replacing `WebView` in your MainActivity's XML with `FragmentContainerView` or `FrameLayout`. You should use some simple layout as fragment container.

Comment: Hi @Miroslav Hýbler. Thanks for your answer. It works!! Now webview appears but I don't find the way to track it... Maybe that's could be another question. Thanks!!